# Correct file path of assets android

Tags: android, file, assets

I'm trying to access the file path of my assets folder but for some reason, I can't access it and it creates an error(Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, Host name may not be null). What should be the correct syntax for this?

This is my code:

```
 String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("file:///android_assets/music.xml");
```

and this is my file location:[image]

Am I doing it properly? Or is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: try this String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("music.xml");

Answer (score 0):

try this, open an input stream on that file.

```
InputStreamReader is= new InputStreamReader(
                context.getAssets().open("abc.xml"));
```

and then open and then

```
    int length = is.available();
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    is.read(data);
  String xmlString = new String(data);
```

Hope It will help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream input = assetManager.open(fileName);
```

And after read file?

Answer (score 0):

try using by filedescriptor as

```
 AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile.txt");
 FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, its working code for text file as well as xml file.

```
public String readFromAssetsFolder(String fileName) {
        String  readValue = "";
        InputStream fileInputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = getResources().getAssets()
                    .open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
            input = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                readValue = readValue+ line;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStreamReader != null)
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                if (fileInputStream != null)
                    fileInputStream.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return readValue;
    }
```